# How to extend interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface UserInstance {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  getFullName(): string;
}
```

```
interface UserExtraDetail {
age: number;
mobileNumber: number
```

Here I have two instances, But if I want to extend the userInstance with userExtraDetail, How should I do this, How can I do this using the keyword **extends** If anyone know please let me know.

Comment: interface UserExtraDetail extends UserInstance {}

Comment: Have you read the TypeScript documentation about [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces)?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface UserInstance extends UserExtraDetail  {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  getFullName(): string;
}
```

Comment: Here my doubt is when I defined the Interface UserInstance I mentioned each variable's type such as id: number, and so on, Then my question is When we extend the interface, why should we redefine each variable type? Here you have done that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to extending an interface as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73379835/438273), interfaces can also be [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) (unlike [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoEkTrHEJZAbwChllgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5zkZgo8A5OEwh08UUAHNOFADZwBQkcjGTpyCRDAAxBjJmDhACgCUosOJBTSAX1KlQkWIhQZsufIRRkKcDXUasHFxMAPYswDIQ-MxsUP4xQbakVBAIclAoCCHuyAyYcWj5OHgESJx50AB01OzIAPR1yCEA1qQVUJU8fGAGELUNTa3tlXIKwv2NLW35lRrauvqKE4PTVb599ZNDM6HhkdGBUMtTw6AAbnAy1AAKUCEADv0AVFwUyAB+n1-f76S3D9AwABPZAAcnOlxud3uoOQVBCEHQ9BCYGQEAAHsA8E0QMhgfcUKDXFBih4kKDKoYAEwAZhpAE5jMgnnUgA)

```ts
interface UserInstance {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  getFullName(): string;
}

interface UserInstance {
  age: number;
  mobileNumber: number;
}

declare const user: UserInstance;
user.id; // ok
user.firstName; // ok
user.lastName; // ok
user.getFullName; // ok
user.age; // ok
user.mobileNumber; // ok
user.invalidProp; /*
     ~~~~~~~~~~~
Property 'invalidProp' does not exist on type 'UserInstance'.(2339) */
```