# Extend an interface with new set of properties based on original interface with mapped types

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, mapped-types

Supposed I have the following interface:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}
```

I want to extend it to have 3 additional properties, one for each of the interfaces' original properties.

So final outcome I want is:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    nameHidden: boolean;
    age: number;
    ageHidden: boolean;
    location: string;
    locationHidden: boolean;
}
```

I was looking into mapped types by TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

But I am unable to figure out how I can achieve this behavior. It only shows examples of how to re-map the existing properties, but not add new ones on top of the existing ones.

Comment: Why does it have to be the **same** interface? I doubt you can update an existing interface with the result of a mapped type. If it can be a different type, it [straightforward enough](https://tsplay.dev/w17n2m).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379803/how-to-extend-interface-in-typescript) of any help? I was trying to find a more upvoted duplicate, but there don't seem to be any (?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It doesn't have to be the same, I just used the same in my example. I want to create another one actually, as an extension. So `PersonWithHide` that would extend `Person` and all its properties, and also automatically add new ones.

Comment: @MikeS. Not really. That is just a basic extend, but I want to automatically generate these new properties in my new interface. I have a lot of places I need to apply this.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to have a new property `${propName}Hidden` for every existing property in the interface. It didn't quite strike me until now :)

Comment: covered directly in the docs [Key Remapping via
as](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You've said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74107684/extend-an-interface-with-new-set-of-properties-based-on-original-interface-with/74107774?noredirect=1#comment130844773_74107684) you don't need it to be the *same* interface. That being the case, you can do this:

```typescript
type WithFlags<T> = T & {
    [Key in keyof T as Key extends string ? `${Key}Hidden` : never]: boolean;
};

type PersonWithFlags = WithFlags<Person>;
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWQAbLAjhhgOGnQYgWBAL4ECYAJ4AHFAHVgYABYAxERwwAeACoA+ZAF5kl5ADJ8bYgG0A0hHXJQyADWvlgwjshwGMg+fhAAHpAgACZRckzIAPzIAAYAJHgxSgASwElJECDZyDQgEABu0AC6NHxYWCIQcCCsSqxqWijoUNggeoYmZvbIY8amjBZDI9as5QimUCgdYMiaNIs4MxPzrJoAdBwQBAD0V8gAehkEZxclZRXXtw9AA)

That creates a new type that is the passed-in type `T` plus a property for every property in it (at least the ones whose names extend `string`) with `Hidden` added to the name and the type `boolean`.

[Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) points out in a comment *(thanks!)* that we can avoid the conditional in that key mapping by using `& string` instead, which is a bit shorter:

```typescript
type WithFlags<T> = T & {
    [Key in keyof T & string as `${Key}Hidden`]: boolean;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWQAbLAjhhgOGnQYgWBAL4ECYAJ4AHFAHVgYABYAxERwwAeACoA+ZAF5kl5ADJ8bYgG0A0hHXJQyADWvlgwji609EzIcBjIAAYAJHg+6koAEsAAJlkQIPEAujR8WFgiEHAgrEqsaloo6FDYIHqGJmb2yK3GpowWjc3WrLkIplAo5WDImjQDON3tfayaAHQcEAQA9JvIAHoA-ASr65k5eVs7B0A)

[pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) points out in a comment that [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) has virtually this same example. They do the remapping like Titian, but in a different place:

```typescript
type WithFlags<T> = T & {
    [Key in keyof T as `${Key & string}Hidden`]: boolean;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0ViWQAbLAjhhgOGnQYgWBAL4ECYAJ4AHFAHVgYABYAxERwwAeACoA+ZAF5kl5ADJ8bYgG0A0hHXJQyADWvlgwjshwGMgABgAkeD5+rnJMSgASwAAmmRAg0QC6NHxYWCIQcCCsSqxqWijoUNggeoYmZvbILcamjBYNTdasOQimUChlYMiaNP04XW29rJoAdBwQBAD0G8gAegD8BCtrGdm5m9v7BEA)

Comment: ``type WithFlags<T> = T & { [Key in keyof T & string as `${Key}Hidden`]: boolean; }`` is shorter but either work :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Ah, cool, thanks! But I wonder: Do we have a dupetarget for this already? I've been looking and struggling to find one, but it seems unlikely we don't have one...

Comment: I am always at a loss to intentionally find anything on SO . It does have a familiar sound to it for sure. Bu I don't think I've seen a question that keeps the mapped fields and the original in the same type like this. could be wrong

Comment: That's very smooth and exactly what I'm looking for. However I would like to know about TS versions, because I am getting an error locally `Parsing error: ']' expected.`. Happens in both versions for `T` and `string` - am I missing something?

Comment: @Axajkamkat what version of TS are you using? The string manipulation part was added in 4.*

Comment: I am using `"typescript": "4.0.8"` in my packages

Comment: This is very cool. If you'd like the additional property to be the same type of the original property, you can change it from `:boolean` to `T[Key]`

Comment: @Axajkamkat Ah.. string manipulation is 4.1 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#41-november-2020 (Template literal types and mapped type 'as' clauses)

Comment: That is unlucky, I have to update my TS probably before I can use it. But I guess I have to one way or another. Thank you for the help and great ideas all of you have provided, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I took `T.J. Crowder`'s answer and modified it a little to make the type a little more (re)usable:

```
type WithFlags<T, TFlag extends string, TValue = null> = T & {
    [Key in keyof T & string as `${Key}${TFlag}`]: TValue extends null ? T[Key] : TValue;
};
```

By default, you have to pass the interface and the flag name, which results in the following type based on the `Person` interface and `TFlag` = `Hidden`:

```
{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  location: string;
  nameHidden: string;
  ageHidden: number;
  locationHidden: string;
}
```

If you want the additional properties to be of a specific type like `boolean` you can adjust the 3rd type parameter `TValue`.

To fulfill your requirements, you can have a helper type like:

```
type WithHiddenFlags<T> = WithFlags<T, 'Hidden', boolean>;
```

and for `WithHiddenFlags<Person>` the resulting type is:

```
{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  location: string;
  nameHidden: boolean;
  ageHidden: boolean;
  locationHidden: boolean;
}
```

The only limitation that I see is that for `TValue = null`, the resulting properties will have the original properties' type instead of `null`.